# sql count instances of a field - microsoft sql server management studio

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-2012

I want a table like below. I have first 2 columns available. I want the count column to have incremental count of values in column name

```
   name marks   count
    a   23        1
    b   43        2
    c   54        3
    d   64        4
    a   12        2
    b   3         2
    a   4         3
```

Comment: @bluefeet And don't forget he needs to show us what he has tried first.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the values in "count" column ? What do they represent?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT name,
       marks,
       Row_number()
         OVER (
           PARTITION BY name
           ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [Count]
FROM   MyTable
```

The rows aren't guaranteed to arrive in any particular order unless you have some way of ordering like the results above that you haven't told us about. There's also no way of knowing which order the ROW_NUMBER will be assigned to all those values with the same name - again - if there is a specific order you'd like to use then use that instead of the `(SELECT 1)` above.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name,
       marks,
       count (id),
FROM   MyTable
group by name, marks
```

Comment: is there a way to say that - 'group by' all columns other than count? I have many more columns